# How to access the files on a Magento site

Tags: magento-1.9, seo, code

A client of mine has a Magento site set up, I've been asked to help them out with the SEO. I've never used Magento before, didn't even know that it exists. I need to find the actual files so I can start making edits to the code. There is a number of errors and faults related to SEO on the site that needs to be changed.

I thought that Magento would have some sort of file directory so I can edit them.

Any help on this would be great.

It wouldn't let me post a comment, so I'll add the version here
the version is 1.9.1.0

Thank you

Comment: Can you please specify Magento Version?

Comment: You need access to the server for file editing, but I do not recommend editing them directly on the server.

Answer (score 0):

I would take a read through this list of tutorials on how to make different changes SEO wise in Magento:

[Magestore Magento SEO](https://www.magestore.com/magento-seo)

Most of them will not involve touching the files you will just need backend access depending on the SEO changes you need to make.

Answer (score 0):

For products, categories and static pages (like homepage) you don't need to access the code and for sure you should not modify the core files to get your result.
You just need admin access.
When editing a category, product or static page you will find 3 fields for meta data. (meta title, description, keywords). For products and categories they are even multilanguage.
Just change the values and you don't need to touch the code.